# Making a form on collection select - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a form that submits on the collection select option, like when I select a value from the dropdown, it should post, what is posted below is not working,

```
<%= form_tag edit_zone_management_path, :method => 'get', :id => "bar" do %>
  <%= collection_select :dropdown, :id, Server.where(:id => @arr),:id, :server_name, :prompt => true, :selected => @sid %>
  <%end%>
```

Can someone please point out what is missing here?

**Addition**

There is some coffeescript that is bound to this collection select.

```
$ ->
$("#dropdown_id").live "change", -> // id of the collection_select

 index = this.selectedIndex


 uid = window.location.pathname.split("/")
 if index == 0
    index += 1
 response = "{ \"key\": { \"value\" : #{index} } }"
 #window.location.replace(uid[0]+ "/" + uid[1] + "/" + uid[2] + "/" + uid[3] + "/" +uid[4])

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/configuration/zone_management/updategrid/',
        data: response,
        contentType: "application/json",

 });
```

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you mean by "is not working"? Does it throw any error? Redirects you to different action?

Comment: Could you also provide your *config/routes.rb*?

Comment: Nothing happens when I select an option, and I haven't defined any routes for this action. Should I add a "get 'edit''' route?

Comment: One more question - do you have any JavaScript related to this form?

Comment: Yes! Previously I was doing this action via javascript, that script is still firing on selecting an option.

Comment: Could you add that JavaScript code as well? This might be related to your problem

Comment: Just added the related coffeescript.

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you have?

Comment: I am not sure just wanna ask how you get `dropdown_id` as `collection_select` id, default it should `model_method`

Comment: @sontya It is the concatenation of first two arguments passed in collection select.

Comment: @PawełDawczak Coffeescript version 1.9

Comment: @Anss - I'm more concerned about version of your jQuery. Second thing - in your CofeeScript, could you change for your `// id of the collection_select` the "//" to "#"? In CoffeScript "#" determines comment, and "//" should cause syntax error...

Comment: @PawełDawczak Jquery version 1.7.1 and I added that comment inside the question textbox :)

Comment: For jQuery 1.7.1 `live` is [depricated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), could you try changing `$("#dropdown_id").live`, to `$("#dropdown_id").on`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing any handler for your `$.ajax` call, try adding some:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST'
  url: '/configuration/zone_management/updategrid/'
  data: response
  contentType: "application/json"
  success: (response) ->
    console.log response
    alert "Success fired"
  error: (response) ->
    console.log response
    alert "Error fired"
 })
```

This is just example, so adjust your handlers accordingly!

Good luck!